# Spring Batch - Could not @Autowired SimpleJobLauncher

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I face the below issue though I have correctly defined SimpleJobLauncher

Description:

Field jobLauncher in com.abcplusd.application.BatchConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher' in your configuration.

The following are my source code..

```
package com.abcplusd.application;

import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchScheduler {
    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean) throws Exception{
        return (JobRepository) factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.abcplusd.application;

import com.abcplusd.application.batch.Process;
import com.abcplusd.application.batch.Reader;
import com.abcplusd.application.batch.Writer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

import java.util.Date;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
    public void sendSMSForBookMark() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Job Started at :"+ new Date());
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID",
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job(), param);
        System.out.println("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
    }
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<String, String> chunk(1)
            .reader(new Reader())
            .processor(new Process())
            .writer(new Writer())
            .build();
    }
}
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Program to interfaces, use `JobLauncher` instead of the concrete type. Also your `job()` and `step1()` should be annotated with `@Bean` to be proper bean definitions currently they aren't. Also remove the `jobRepository` method as the factory automatically creates a `JobRepository`.

Comment: In my case there is no such error in while running my spring boot application locally but error occured only in one of our Test server... Why this is so weird? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

It works fine when removed `@Configuration` from BatchScheduler class.

So answer is

```
package com.abcplusd.application;

import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
public class BatchScheduler {
    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean) throws Exception{
        return (JobRepository) factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which makes this class unused and use te Spring Boot / Batch defaults.

Comment: @M.Deinum If i am not wrong @Import({BatchScheduler.class}) makes the above class usable.

Comment: No it doesn't. It still isn't a proper configuration class but rather a bean lite implementation (check the reference guide on that). However with Spring Boot you won't need it as that will autoconfigure Spring Batch for you. Just remove that class and place `@EnableScheduled` on your already existing configuration class.  I would suggest to place those 2 `@Enable` annotations on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, that way you have that in all place and your configuration is then only your job definition.