# My Project is JPA Based. No XML configuration. Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type JobLauncher to autowire

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

My project uses JPA annotation rather than spring XML to configure and annotate beans. I have NO  web.xml, applicationConfigutaion.xml nothing xml based configuration in my entire project. How do I resolve this issue.

I'm getting this

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at com.process.batch.job.MyBatchJobApplication.main(MyBatchJobApplication.java:54)
```

Comment: Have you provided, "@Component" annotation in JobLauncher ?

Comment: No. Can not. I imported it from org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher

Comment: @Titi don't you have to define a `@Bean` annotated method that returns a JobLauncher?

Comment: Show your code what you have done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch - Could not @Autowired SimpleJobLauncher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436301/spring-batch-could-not-autowired-simplejoblauncher)

Comment: I did not need to define @Bean annotated method to return JobLauncher. This is the line of code I have in my Main Method to start the Job.                                                                            ApplicationContext ctx = configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
  JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
  JobExplorer jobExplorer = (JobExplorer) ctx.getBean("jobExplorer");
  Job job = (Job) ctx.getBean(jobName);
  JobExecution jobExecution = startNewJob(jobExplorer, jobLauncher, job);